# Why is f(Double x) a better match than f(double... x)?

Tags: java

Today I was studying for an incoming Java exam and I ran into this question:

> Let `A` be a class defined as follows:
>
> ```
> class A {
>     public void f(Double x) { System.out.println("A.f(Double)"); }
>     public void f(double... x) { System.out.println("A.f(double...)"); }
> }
> ```
>
> What is the output produced by the instruction `A a = new A(); a.f(1.0);`?

The answer seems to be `A.f(Double)` but I can't understand why. Could someone give me a proper explanation?

Comment: The output produced is your team lead saying "That's horrible code. Find a way to write it that doesn't mean people have to know the Java spec inside out."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Overload resolution always favours a function with an explicit number of arguments over a function with a variable argument list, even if that means that `1.0` is auto-boxed.

In a little more detail, a function is chosen with this precedence according to [JLS 15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

1. Type widening
2. Auto-boxing
3. Variable arguments

Comment: Yes, that is in some situations really ugly. In the current case only `f(new double[] {1.0})` seems to work.

Comment: (Overload resolution in C++ is even more complex ;-) )

Comment: [Overload resolution in C♯ is NP-hard: You can encode any 3-SAT problem as an overload resolution problem and have the compiler solve it.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five/) Do you happen to know how "hard" Java's overload resolution is?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I find it interesting that language writers decline to include even simple forms of overloading based on return types, because that would be "too hard", but then they put in NP-hard resolution rules for argument overloading.  I wouldn't mind a requirement that overloads be marked as "primary" and "secondary", with exactly one  "primary" overload for each argument signature.  Implementations could as a two step process pick the best argument signature and then pick the best overload with that signature (using the primary one if no alternative is *clearly* better).