# Is primitive int also a Comparable?

Tags: java, generics

I just came across a Java generics tutorial that seems to use primitive int, float, etc. as objects that extend Comparable

```
    public class MaximumTest {
   // determines the largest of three Comparable objects

   public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z) {
      T max = x;   // assume x is initially the largest

      if(y.compareTo(max) > 0) {
         max = y;   // y is the largest so far
      }

      if(z.compareTo(max) > 0) {
         max = z;   // z is the largest now                 
      }
      return max;   // returns the largest object   
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.printf("Max of %d, %d and %d is %d\n\n", 
         3, 4, 5, maximum( 3, 4, 5 ));

      System.out.printf("Max of %.1f,%.1f and %.1f is %.1f\n\n",
         6.6, 8.8, 7.7, maximum( 6.6, 8.8, 7.7 ));

      System.out.printf("Max of %s, %s and %s is %s\n","pear",
         "apple", "orange", maximum("pear", "apple", "orange"));
   }
}
```

Can primitive be a Comparable object somehow?

Comment: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is what's going on here - primitive `int` values are boxed into `java.lang.Integer` objects, and that implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

Comment: Autoboxing is what you're looking for, converting between primitive types and their counterpart objects whereever necessary (for example `int` <--> `Integer`).

Comment: It's a little more intricate than mere autoboxing. It's that plus the rules of overload resolution.

Comment: The thing to note is that `T` cannot be a primitive type, it’s always a reference type. So to be able to call the generic method, Java has to box the values, which happens automatically. To `Integer` in the first example, to `Double` in the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally this is due to how your Java compiler is required to consider **overload resolution**. If an overload for your type is not found, then an overload that *widens* the type is considered. If no such overload exists, then one that would cause your primitive types to be *auto-boxed* to the corresponding boxed type is considered. A function specified with generics *is* an appropriate candidate.

In your case, the appropriate overload

`public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z)`

*can* be found, and compilation is successful.

---

A function is chosen with this precedence according to [JLS 15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

1. Type widening
2. Auto-boxing
3. Variable arguments

(Taken from my answer [Why is f(Double x) a better match than f(double... x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652947/why-is-fdouble-x-a-better-match-than-fdouble-x/41652977#41652977))

Answer (score 4):

The primitive will be autoboxed to wrapper object which implements `Comparable`. 
`int val = 3;` will became an `Integer` [autoboxing and unboxing java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)